# How to rename the site column's field title within a list definition?

Tags: 2013, solution-package, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to rename a field title from a list definition. I have the following schema.xml:

```
<List ...> <MetaData> <Fields> ... 
      <Field ID="{2684f9f2-54be-429f-ba06-76754fc056bf}" Type="DateTime" Name="EndDate" 
           DisplayName="End date and time" Format="DateTime" Sealed="TRUE" Required="TRUE" 
           Filterable="FALSE" FilterableNoRecurrence="TRUE" Indexed="TRUE" 
           StaticName="EndDate">
        <Default>[today]</Default>
        <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef Name="fAllDayEvent" RefType="AllDayEvent" />
        </FieldRefs>
      </Field> ...
```

But the value of DisplayName does not get transferred over to the list's field title. What do I need to change? Strangely one can easily modify it afterwards via the GUI.

I am using SharePoint 2013 Server with Visual Studio 2013 update 4 to build the sandbox wsp solution.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely the behavior is completely in my favor when I start working with a ContentTypeRef or ContentType element! 
Working example i.e.

```
<List ... EnableContentTypes="TRUE"> 
   <MetaData> 
      <ContentTypes> 
          <ContentType ID="..." Name="..."> 
          </ContentType> 
      </ContentTypes> 
      <Fields>...
```

Don't include FieldRef elements as this will copy over the Site Column field definition, overwriting your list level DisplayName values.

One remaining surprise: only StartDate / EventDate and EndDate still don't want to get renamed through a DisplayName attribute.